# Help with PuTTY Terminal Settings - Unrecognized Characters

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-9.10, putty, character-encoding

I am running PuTTY on Windows 7/64-bit laptop.  I am connecting to an Ubuntu 9.10/64-bit system running OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-6ubuntu2.  When I am running some command, the output contains unrecognized characters, like this:

```
mod_helloworld.c:1: error: expected â)â before â*â token
mod_helloworld.c:28: error: expected â)â before â*â token
mod_helloworld.c:33: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âAP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATAâ
```

However, when I run this command from a terminal directly on the Ubuntu system, the output is clear:

```
mod_helloworld.c:1: error: expected `)` before `*` token
mod_helloworld.c:28: error: expected `)` before `*` token
mod_helloworld.c:33: error: expected `=`, `,`, `;`, `asm` or `__attribute__` before `AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA`
```

So it appears to be the "back-tick" character causing the problem.  Any idea how I can correct this via PuTTY settings?

Thanks,
-aj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PuTTY is interpreting the characters being sent by the terminal incorrectly.

You can change the character set under the **Window** category in the **Translation** settings.  Change the **Received data assumed to be in which character set:** to the correct character set.  `UTF-8` worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, UTF-8 is particularly useful when running some curses apps