# Putty color scheme for all saved sessions and default

Tags: putty

I want to change the color scheme of all saved sessions and the default scheme.
Is there a smarter way then generating .reg files with the new scheme for each session?
How do I change the default colors for new session?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the PuTTY character set for all saved sessions](https://superuser.com/questions/201662/changing-the-putty-character-set-for-all-saved-sessions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For existing sessions you can export the .reg file, replace all occurences of colors with your desired values and reimport the file. If that is not "smart" enough, you can try replacing directly in registry with some programs listed here https://superuser.com/questions/174942/registry-search-replace-tool

For future sessions, you can modify settings of the session named "Default settings" and they will be inherited by new sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExtraPuTTY to save your reg profiles into ini's then copy the colour values from the one you want and paste them back in, then load up ExtraPuTTY in Reg mode and load and save each profile that doesn't have [Reg] beside it