# How can I type Umlaut characters in a Putty session

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty, german

I am trying to type some German characters in my putty session. I am able to type it on notepad or other editors.

```
asdÆ²as
```

But when I try to paste the above text on my Putty session, nothing happens (i.e. nothing gets echoed).

My Putty Configuration -> Window -> Translation -> Remote Character set has ISO-8859-1:1998 Latin-1, West Europe. I tried a few other character sets and I am not able to type Umlaut characters.

Is there some other setting to make sure that I can type Umlaut characters in a Putty session ?

Comment: Related:  http://superuser.com/q/91433/820  The answer is probably the same, check your translation setting for both your shell and in PuTTY.

Comment: What character set should I use to get Umlaut characters. I am having ISO-8859-1:1998 Latin-1, West Europe. I tried a few others and still I am not able to type Umlaut chracters.

Comment: I would try UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to enter it if you know the ASCII value by *holding down* the <kbd>Alt</kbd> while entering the number from the numeric keypad; e.g. U-umlaut is **<kbd>Alt</kbd>0220**.

This works for *some* characters in CMD prompt, but may need the changes @heavyd references.